Load a vite react-ts app from a traditional backend: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble
I used the Vite template in order to generate a React TypeScript app:
npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template react-ts
I want to load the app in a traditional server-side generated backend. So I followed the guide here.
I have the following in the <head>:
<script type="module">
            import RefreshRuntime from 'http://localhost:5173/@react-refresh'
            RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
            window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
            window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
            window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
        </script>
        <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script>

And then this in the "content" area:
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/src/main.tsx"></script>

All files loads perfectly fine and all, but I recieve an error in the console:
App.tsx:1 Uncaught Error: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201
    at App.tsx:1:33

The discussion linked seems unrelevant to my issue and I have put import 'vite/modulepreload-polyfill' in the top of my main.tsx file.
What do I do wrong here? Seems like this is broken somehow.
I have fiddled with different Vite settings but nothing seems to help.
